# Remote does not have refs avaialble for fetch exception

Tags: jgit

While cherrypicking changes from gerrit, JGit often throws the exception Remote does not have refs/changes/xx/xxxxx avaialble for fetch exception
This seems to be intermittent. After few retires, the error does not appear. Does anybody know why this exception occurs?